# /setprivacy is not working with my Telegram bot

Tags: telegram-bot

In the process of adding Telegram bot to a group, the /setprivacy is set to Enable, so that whenever the user mention the bot using the username of bot or '/', the bot will get the message. Despite of this enable setting, the bot still receives the query from the user and replying to it.

More info:-

1. I set the bot as a Administrator of that group to access message
2. /setprivacy status Enabled (I tried switching it to Disabled and Enable it again, not working)

Anyone please help me on this issue.

Thanks

Comment: please remove the `python-telegram-bot` tag, as this question is about telegram bots in general and not about that library in particular ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bot set as administrator will *always* receive *all* messages, no matter the privacy setting. See https://core.telegram.org/bots#privacy-mode.

> Privacy mode is enabled by default for all bots, except bots that were
> added to the group as admins (bot admins always receive all messages).

You need to either revoke your bot's admin status or program your bot not to reply to a user's query.

Comment: So as per the documentation, we can't able to get the user text unless the bot becomes admin of that group, right?

Comment: You **can** get user messages even with non-admin bot. Just note it depends what this text looks like. Message will be visible when starting with `/`, or are direct reply to the bot . Whereas admin bots have privilege to read _any_ message.